# Multi-Class Classification With Logistic Regression On Binary Data

Tags: machine-learning, regression, logistic-regression, multiclass-classification

I am trying to implement a multi-class classifier with using logistic regression. In my dataset, attributes are words, for example first attribute is 1 if the data instance includes word "x" and it is 0 if it does not include the word "x", so all of my attributes are binary.

I partially understood how to implement multi-class logistic regression for categorical data from here https://github.com/tpeng/logistic-regression/blob/master/src/Logistic.java. However I could not figured out how to decide the weights when the attributes are binary. I found some academical articles about it but it is too heavy for me. I think this is really simple and well-known thing. How can I do that?

Comment: Have you implemented gradient descent?

Comment: No I did not implemented gradient descent. I need to implement a multi-class classifier with logistic regression for binary attributes only. Can you suggest me anything, a resource that explains it simply maybe good. @Media

Comment: The fact that you have binary inputs does not change anything significantly, try to use tensorflow or keras. You just need put layers together. The backprop will be computed automatically.

Comment: @Media Thanks for the advise, I want to implement myself without using any framework or library. Can you tell me that when we create a training model in Logistic Regression for binary attributes, how can I find the weight values. For example, in the code that share it's link, it multiplies the value of the attributes with some other values but since my attributes is binary I can not do that. So, what should I use instead of that?

Comment: You should not set the weights, they should be trained. I have a suggestion. In coursera, take the course of pr. Ng about ML. I don't remember it was from which chapter but it is implemented from scratch in the homeworks of that course. It will lead you step by step.

Comment: @Media Man I did not mean anything like setting the weights, what I wanted to say what should be the way to find the weights when the data is binary?

Comment: The training process does not change. Suppose you have mnist data and you set a threshold and make the intensity values to binary values, you model may learn it easier but the **training** process does **not** change.

Comment: @Media Thanks for your answers. I thought that the way of doing training should be change but now I understand. If you organize your comments within an answer I will accept it and maybe some others can get benefit from it. And one more thing, I analysed the code that I mentioned in my question but I did not see anything wrong, could you just quickly check it out to see if anything is wrong, if you have time. Thanks again,

Comment: For forward path, all you have to do is to find the inner product of the weights and input features. It can be done simply by a for loop.